# Error message from worker: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Unknown reply:

Tags: redis, google-cloud-dataflow, redis-cluster, google-cloud-memorystore

While connecting to memorystore through dataflow getting the below exception in the dataflow worker logs.

'''Error message from worker: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Unknown reply: redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:140) redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:192) redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:316) redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getStatusCodeReply(Connection.java:243) redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.ping(Jedis.java:356) org.redis.memorystore.redisconn1.processElement(memorystore.java:39)'''

Please find the code which I am using.

```
class redisconn1 extends DoFn<String,String>
{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(redisconn1.class);
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws ParseException, IOException, InterruptedException
        {
                String line = c.element();
                Jedis jedis = new Jedis("12.08.64.4", 6378);
                LOG.info("Connection to server sucessfully");
                LOG.info("Server is running: "+jedis.ping());

        }
}
public class redisconn
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                DataflowPipelineOptions options =PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
                options.setProject("heg-dev-rtstdo-0");//project_id
                options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);//Runner type
                options.setRegion("us-east4");//region
                options.setTemplateLocation("gs://heg-dev-rtstdo-0-devlopment_dataflow/DataflowSinkJobs/redis_template/TemplateNag");
                options.setGcpTempLocation("gs://heg-dev-rtstdo-0-devlopment_dataflow/DataflowSinkJobs/TempFolder/redis_temp");
                options.setAutoscalingAlgorithm(DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions.AutoscalingAlgorithmType.THROUGHPUT_BASED);
                Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
                
                p.apply(Create.of("Hello world")).apply(ParDo.of(new redisconn1()));

                p.run();

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For external connetions on dataflow it is best to use beam.sdk.io.
For redis  `org.apache.beam.sdk.io.redis.RedisIO;`
For  enriching data from redis in a DoFn you can use the pattern outlined in https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/guide-to-common-cloud-dataflow-use-case-patterns-part-1

```
public  class ToKVFunction extends DoFn
   private Jedis redis;

  @Override
  public void startBundle(){
    this.redis = RedisConnectionConfiguration.crete("12.08.64.4", 6378)
  }

     
  @ProcessElement
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws ParseException, IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        String line = c.element();
        // this.redis.hget(...)

    }
 
    @Override
    public void finishBundle(){
     this.redis.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what if I want to access memory store Redis instance in the pardo function. Because we are dealing with huge amount of data in Realtime. Also do you have any sample code for the above Skelton which you have shared.

Comment: In this case you can use the pattern outlined in 
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/guide-to-common-cloud-dataflow-use-case-patterns-part-1
and RedisConnectionConfiguration to instantiate a jedis conneciton once per pardo bundle

Answer (score 0):

hh

I have tried with  beam.sdk.io to connect to the memory store. But I am still getting the same exception.

Please find the code which I used.

```
public class memorystore 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        DataflowPipelineOptions options =PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
        options.setProject("vz-it-np-gh2v-dev-rtstdo-0");//project_id
        options.setRunner(DataflowRunner.class);//Runner type
        options.setRegion("us-east4");//region
        options.setTemplateLocation("gs://vz-it-np-gh2v-dev-rtstdo-0-devlopment_dataflow/DataflowSinkJobs/redis_template/TemplateNag");
        options.setGcpTempLocation("gs://vz-it-np-gh2v-dev-rtstdo-0-devlopment_dataflow/DataflowSinkJobs/TempFolder/redis_temp");
        options.setAutoscalingAlgorithm(DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions.AutoscalingAlgorithmType.THROUGHPUT_BASED);
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

        
        RedisConnectionConfiguration redisConfig = RedisConnectionConfiguration.create()
                                                   .withHost("100.68.64.4")
                                                   .withPort(6378)
                                                   .withAuth("e7cce2ef-7fb1-47ff-bc8f-8bfb5d936b0c");

        PCollection<KV<String, String>> output1=pipeline.apply(Create.of(KV.of("a", "1"), KV.of("b", "2"), KV.of("a", "3"), KV.of("c", "4")));
        
        
        output1.apply(ParDo.of(new ToKVFunction()))
                .apply(RedisIO.write().withMethod(Write.Method.SADD).withConnectionConfiguration(redisConfig));

        pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
    }

    // Function to convert your data to KV format (Key-Value)
    public static class ToKVFunction extends DoFn<KV<String, String>, KV<String, String>> 
    {
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            KV<String, String> input = c.element();
            String key = "GCP";
            String value = "1";
            c.output(KV.of(key, value));
        }
    }
}
```

Please find the exception which I am getting.

```
Error message from worker: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Unknown reply: org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory$1.typedApply(IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:178) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory$1.typedApply(IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:149) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.graph.Networks$TypeSafeNodeFunction.apply(Networks.java:67) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.graph.Networks$TypeSafeNodeFunction.apply(Networks.java:54) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.graph.Networks.replaceDirectedNetworkNodes(Networks.java:91) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.create(IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:109) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.doWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:267) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:221) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:147) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:127) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:114) java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UnboundedScheduledExecutorService$ScheduledFutureTask.run(UnboundedScheduledExecutorService.java:163) java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Unknown reply: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:39) org.apache.beam.sdk.io.redis.RedisIO$Write$WriteFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeSetup(Unknown Source) org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.reflect.DoFnInvokers.tryInvokeSetupFor(DoFnInvokers.java:53) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DoFnInstanceManagers$ConcurrentQueueInstanceManager.deserializeCopy(DoFnInstanceManagers.java:86) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DoFnInstanceManagers$ConcurrentQueueInstanceManager.peek(DoFnInstanceManagers.java:68) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.UserParDoFnFactory.create(UserParDoFnFactory.java:100) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DefaultParDoFnFactory.create(DefaultParDoFnFactory.java:75) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.createParDoOperation(IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:248) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.access$000(IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:80) org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory$1.typedApply(IntrinsicMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:167) ... 15 more Suppressed: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:39) at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.redis.RedisIO$Write$WriteFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeTeardown(Unknown Source) at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.reflect.DoFnInvokers.tryInvokeSetupFor(DoFnInvokers.java:56) ... 22 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.redis.RedisIO$Write$WriteFn.teardown(RedisIO.java:811) Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Unknown reply: redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.process(Protocol.java:140) redis.clients.jedis.Protocol.read(Protocol.java:192) redis.clients.jedis.Connection.readProtocolWithCheckingBroken(Connection.java:316) redis.clients.jedis.Connection.getStatusCodeReply(Connection.java:243) redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.auth(Jedis.java:2625) org.apache.beam.sdk.io.redis.RedisConnectionConfiguration.connect(RedisConnectionConfiguration.java:143) org.apache.beam.sdk.io.redis.RedisIO$Write$WriteFn.setup(RedisIO.java:684)
```

Please let me know how can we resolve the same.